# How to display uploaded files name on UI

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

http://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/09/25/file-upload-lightning-component/#comment-22015

In the above link we have file-upload-lightning-component which help to upload files and display the filename which you have upload. But my requirement is display the file names which is already displayed.

for example

For the first time i am uploading file file1 and it displays the name but when trying to upload second file  file2 it has to display file1 and file 2 name both on UI but it only displaying file which is uploading.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check what the `console.log` statement says for the `fileName` attribute on `handleFilesChange` function.

`fileName` attribute is also a single string value, you can change that to a `string[]` or append the item name as they are added to the original string value.

Chrome dev tools, `debugger;` and `console.log` statements are your friend.